# Checkpoint directory for spark applications in synapse

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

How do I set a valid spark checkpoint directory for spark pools in synapse analytics?

In azure databricks I used the following (c# for spark):

**sparkSession.SparkContext.SetCheckpointDir(@"/tmp")**

However the same thing on synapse gives a warning:

> 22/07/07 23:00:00 WARN SparkContext: Spark is not running in local
> mode, therefore the checkpoint directory must not be on the local
> filesystem. Directory '/tmp' appears to be on the local filesystem.

If I don't provide any checkpoint directory at all then I get failures on the executors:

> [2022-07-15T23:34:20.7303213Z] [vm-5ac13716] [Error] [JvmBridge]
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Checkpoint directory has not been set
> in the SparkContext   at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.checkpoint(RDD.scala:1622)   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$checkpoint$1(Dataset.scala:691)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3687)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:107)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:181)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:94)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:68)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3685)  at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.checkpoint(Dataset.scala:688)    at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.checkpoint(Dataset.scala:651)    at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.spark.api.dotnet.DotnetBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(DotnetBackendHandler.scala:165)
> at
> org.apache.spark.api.dotnet.DotnetBackendHandler.$anonfun$handleBackendRequest$2(DotnetBackendHandler.scala:105)
> at
> org.apache.spark.api.dotnet.ThreadPool$$anon$1.run(ThreadPool.scala:34)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the Spark cluster is distributed (i.e on different physicial nodes), you should set the checkpoint in a shared directory, which can be though HDFS, S3, or NFS.
Without this requirement, Spark won't be able to commit, as each node of the Spark cluster must be able to access files from other node

Comment: Thanks Gregoire,  Yes, on azure databricks the checkpoint was writing to their proprietary dbfs.

Oddly, my checkpoint operations in synapse spark seem to be working, despite the warning about attempting to use /tmp.  I will keep investigating.

Answer (score 1):

Synapse will automagically use an abfss storage account to keep checkpoints.  You can give it a relative path like so:

**spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("tmp1234")**

[image]